# Getting issue while dumping data from Add-In to Excel 2016(Build 16.9029)

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2016, excel-addins

We have an Excel Add-in (created by us) that fetches data from the server and dumps into excel. It was working fine until the Excel's new **Build release (16.9029.*)**. After this update, All data is getting fetched correctly from the server but can't be dumped into excel sheet and It shows Error that "Microsoft Excel has stopped working".

When I tried to debug the issue. I found that after **"QueryTables.BeforeRefresh"** event occurs, Excel suddenly crashed & shows Error that **"Microsoft Excel has stopped working".**

Here is the sample code which we can provide to you.

**Explanation of the code:**

```
'Some logic here for our add-in Webquery (URL more than 1000 character)
 Public Sub createQueryTable(URL As String, dest As String)

      Dim oBk As Workbook
      Dim x As New clsQueryTable
      Dim oQT As QueryTable
      Dim i As Integer
      Dim strFileName As String
      Dim posturl, postdata As String
      Dim instrstart, instrend As Integer

If Not Mid(URL, Len(URL) - 12, Len(URL)) = "&format=.html" Then
strFileName = URL & "&format=.html"
Else
strFileName = URL
End If

On Error Resume Next
       ActiveSheet.Range(dest).QueryTable.ResultRange.ClearContents
       ActiveSheet.Range(dest).QueryTable.Delete
On Error GoTo errorhandler 
With ActiveSheet
    Set oQT = .QueryTables.Add( _
                Connection:="URL;" & strFileName, _
                Destination:=Range(dest))
End With
Dim flagcheck As Boolean
flagcheck = False
With oQT

    'State that we're selecting a specific table
    .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
    .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
    .EnableRefresh = True

    'Import the 1st table on the page
    .WebTables = "1"


    'Ignore the web page's formatting
    .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingAll

    'Do not try to recognize dates
    .WebDisableDateRecognition = True

    'Don't automatically refresh the query each time the file is opened
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False

    'Waiting for the query to complete before continuing
    .BackgroundQuery = True

    'Save the query data with the workbook
    .SaveData = True

    'Adjust column widths to autofit new data
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .PreserveFormatting = True
End With
'Perform the query, waiting for it to complete
Set x.qt = oQT
Set outputCell = Range(dest)

x.qt.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False 'From this it calls qt_BeforeRefresh. 
Set x = Nothing
Exit Sub

errorhandler:
   'On Error Resume Next
    If Err.Number = 1004 Then
          MsgBox "URL length exceeds the limit. Remove " & 
         Len(x.qt.Connection) - 222 & " from URL"
         Err.Clear
    Else
        MsgBox Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description
    End If
      Set x = Nothing
 End Sub

Private Sub qt_BeforeRefresh(Cancel As Boolean)
     Debug.Print "hiii" 'It is printed Succesfully
 End Sub 'After this point of debug Excel Crashed So further execution also 
          stops.
```

We have some logic for our AddIn which fetches data from the server & print it into the Excel Sheet.

Once the data fetched it goes to the **"QueryTable"** function & in the end we have used Refresh method of Excel which executes the **"BeforeRefresh" Event** & after executing this method; **Excel stopped working.**

We have put the debug point in that method for testing which executed in the end.

One more thing we found in that, there might be an issue with **Request URL length in newer release(16.9029.*)**.

Earlier it was fetching up to **1800 characters** in the request URL (web query) but now it's only **250** ( as per our testing). Request URL above then this character causes issues & stopped the execution of Excel.
We haven't found any documentation for the newer build of Excel. Does anyone have any idea about this?

Any help would be much appreciated. We are stuck at this point.

Looking forward for the suggestions.

Thanks & Regards,